# Reshape data long to wide in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, reshape

I have a table that I want to pivot/reshape from long to wide.

```
The long format has 3 columns: 
  zipcode, category, zipnum
  '12345', 'A', '1'
  '40348', 'A', '2'
  '16132', 'B', '1'
  '09428', 'B', '2'
  '14818', 'B', '3'
  '93182', 'C', '1'
```

The column zipnum is the row number for each zip code, grouped by category. So zipnum is unique for each zipcode within a category. The wide format that I am trying to achieve has the columns category, zipcode1, ..., zipcodeN, where N is the maximum value of zipnum in the entire table. In this example N=3, but in my actual dataset N is about 2000.

```
   category, zipcode1, zipcode2, zipcode3
   'A', '12345', '40348', NULL
   'B', '16132', '09428', '14818'
   'C', '93182', NULL, NULL
```

I'm relatively new to SQL - I know how to do this very easily in Python, R, etc. but can't find a way to do it with MySQL. To be frank I don't really even know where to start.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of zipcodes per category?

Comment: I will have to do this a few times, but in some instances it might be as high as ~2000. And typically the maximum will be no less than 1000.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: When you get a solutiion, it is very bad to delete the question as if it is mocking the person who answered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you combine them into a single comma-separated string:

```
select category,
       group_concat(zip_code order by zipnum) as zip_codes
from t
group by category;
```

Because your string will be so long, you will need to set [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to a value larger than its default value.

Why don't you want these as columns?  Well, MySQL has a hard limit of 4,096 columns in a table and I think this limit applies to result sets as well.  [The limit, though, is further complicated by the storage engine and other settings.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html). There is enough complication that I just wouldn't want to dynamically be creating queries that could result in thousands of columns.

You might find that a JSON structure is more convenient than a "mere" string.  MySQL also supports that.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I agree that this is probably a better approach. A follow up question - how would I do then go backwards? ie. taking the single comma-separated string and reshaping back into the long format. I will need to do this as well

Comment: @linkspan . . . That is awkward in MySQL, but you can use `substring_index()` to extract particular elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something that isn't easy to do using SQL. For example, there is a separate library for doing this in PostgreSQL (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html)).

But `dbplyr` may help here, either used directly or used indirectly to generate SQL that you can use outside of that package. I don't have MySQL, so I tested the following on PostgreSQL and SQLite. I think it should work with `RMySQL` too:

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~zipcode, ~category, ~zipnum,
'12345', 'A', '1',
'40348', 'A', '2',
'16132', 'B', '1',
'09428', 'B', '2',
'14818', 'B', '3',
'93182', 'C', '1')

pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())

df_pg <- copy_to(pg, df, overwrite = TRUE)

df_pg %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "zipnum", values_from = "zipcode",
                names_prefix = "zipcode")
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
#> # Database: postgres [iangow@/tmp:5432/crsp]
#>   category zipcode3 zipcode2 zipcode1
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 A        <NA>     40348    12345   
#> 2 C        <NA>     <NA>     93182   
#> 3 B        14818    09428    16132

df_pg %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "zipnum", values_from = "zipcode",
                names_prefix = "zipcode") %>%
    show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT "category", MAX(CASE WHEN ("zipnum" = '3') THEN ("zipcode") END) AS "zipcode3", MAX(CASE WHEN ("zipnum" = '2') THEN ("zipcode") END) AS "zipcode2", MAX(CASE WHEN ("zipnum" = '1') THEN ("zipcode") END) AS "zipcode1"
#> FROM "df"
#> GROUP BY "category"

df_sqlite <- dbplyr::memdb_frame(df)

df_sqlite %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "zipnum", values_from = "zipcode",
                names_prefix = "zipcode") 
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.35.2 [:memory:]
#>   category zipcode1 zipcode2 zipcode3
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 A        12345    40348    <NA>    
#> 2 B        16132    09428    14818   
#> 3 C        93182    <NA>     <NA>

df_sqlite %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "zipnum", values_from = "zipcode",
                names_prefix = "zipcode") %>%
    show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT `category`, MAX(CASE WHEN (`zipnum` = '1') THEN (`zipcode`) END) AS `zipcode1`, MAX(CASE WHEN (`zipnum` = '2') THEN (`zipcode`) END) AS `zipcode2`, MAX(CASE WHEN (`zipnum` = '3') THEN (`zipcode`) END) AS `zipcode3`
#> FROM `dbplyr_001`
#> GROUP BY `category`
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>